# iOs: Swift Google Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I am new to iOs development and would like to implement Google Analytics (swift).

**It appears there is some missing information on implementing Google Analytics in swift on** [Google's instruction page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift):

[image]

It seems the import statement above is incorrect, can anyone assist me with the missing/correct statement?

**Exta Info:**

- I come from a Java background and IDEs I use import for you, so
  please excuse my stupidity.
- I have cocopods installed, and use other pods: Almofire, Fabric, swiftyJson etc
- I am developing for iOs 8
- Instructions above this, are clear and working. Installing the pods/config file etc

Comment: With my limited experience, the highlighted import statement appears to be a botched objective c import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your Pods folder in Xcode you can see the available pods there. Most of them usually have a file that contains all import statements for any files needed. In this case its the Analytics.h file in `Pods/Google/Analytics/`

I'm guessing that, to import this file in your bridging header (which I hope you have, if not let me know), you can use `#import "Google/Analytics.h"`.

It also says a little bit lower on the page, to import the `<Google/Analytics.h>` to the header.

[image: Picture showing text on google page]

Answer (score 4):

In your Objective-C bridging header file, You should import GA header files:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

I am not sure if I am missing some import.